# Given two buckets each containing an identical set of balls, each ball with two colored numbers, does a certain matching algorithm scale as N^2?

Tags: performance, math, combinations, scaling, combinatorics

For a client, I have a scaling problem that I have boiled down to the following fundamental combinatorics problem.

Suppose there is a bucket containing `N` balls, each ball with a random red number and a random blue number written on it.  (Assume all numbers are positive integers.)

Suppose there is a second bucket with an identical set of balls (i.e., it also has `N` balls and the balls exactly correspond to the balls in the first bucket, in terms of the numbers written on the balls.)

The question I'd like to answer for my client as efficiently as possible for large `N` in a computer program is the following:

Consider every possible pairing of balls between the two buckets (i.e., one ball from the first bucket and one ball from the second bucket).  How many such pairs satisfy the condition that the product of the two red numbers in the pair is the same as the product of the two blue numbers in the pair?

The question here for StackOverflow is: Is the most efficient possible algorithm to solve this problem `O(N^2)`?  I think so, but I cannot prove it.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a general computer science question, not a specific programming problem. programmers.stackexchange.com is a better fit, or possibly mathematics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DanielMann Do you *also* think it is a poor question that should be downvoted - or just that it should be closed as off-topic?

Comment: @Dan: It's a well formulated question, but it isn't a *practical* programming question.  You haven't specified a language or provided any code; questions aren't practical without that.  But you can flag a moderator to migrate it (In the flag message, remind them you're the author)

Comment: @DanielMann I debated which site to post on, and found `a software algorithm` listed as an appropriate question for StackOverflow, so I posted here.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  I have an `O(N)` solution, involving a hashtable on the (reduced) ratio of `red_value/blue_value` for one of the buckets. Filling this hashtable is `O(N)`.  Matching `blue_value/red_value` from the other bucket against this table is also `O(N)`, since each lookup is `O(1)`.

It's a hashtable, not a hashset, because there can be multiple balls with the same ratio.

One can also use a trie for `O(1)` lookups.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Would the `O(N)` scaling also extend to 3 or more buckets (matching on the product of all three (or more) red numbers against all three (or more) blue numbers)?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: No, that's `O(N^2)` in the number of balls per bucket.  It will also increase with the number of buckets, probably linearly.  I think overall `O(M*N^(M-1))` worst case, although you probably won't have `N^(M-1)` distinct ratios, so average case is better.

Comment: Actually because the numbers are constrained to be equal in all buckets, you're guaranteed to repeat ratios.  A lot.  So you might get to divide by `2^M` or so.